# Unable to get jquery to work, i have tried debugging but not working

Tags: jquery, flexbox

```js
$(function() {
    $(".toggle").on("click", function() {
        if ($(".item").hasClass("active")) {
            $(".item").removeClass("active");
            $(this).find("a").html("<i class='fas fa-bars'></i>");
        } else {
            $(".item").addClass("active");
            $(this).find("a").html("<i class='fas fa-times'></i>");
        }
    });
});
```

```css
nav {
    background: #222;
    padding: 5px 20px;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.logo a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.menu li {
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 15px 5px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.logo a,
.toggle a {
    font-size: 20px;
}
/* Mobile menu */
.menu {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
.toggle {
    order: 1;
}
.item.button {
    order: 2;
}
.item {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    order: 3;
    display: none;
}
.item.active {
    display: block;
}
/* Tablet menu */
@media all and (min-width: 600px) {
    .menu {
        justify-content: center;
    }
    .logo {
        flex: 1;
    }
    .toggle {
        flex: 1;
        text-align: right;
    }
    .item.button {
        width: auto;
        order: 1;
        display: block;
    }
    .toggle {
        order: 2;
    }
    .button.secondary {
        border: 0;
    }
    .button a {
        padding: 7.5px 15px;
        background: teal;
        border: 1px #006d6d solid;
    }
    .button.secondary a {
        background: transparent;    
    }
    .button a:hover {
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    .button:not(.secondary) a:hover {
        background: #006d6d;
        border-color: #005959;
    }
    .button.secondary a:hover {
        color: #ddd;
    } 
}
/* Desktop menu */
@media all and (min-width: 900px) {
    .item {
        display: block;
        width: auto;
    }
    .toggle {
        display: none;
    }
    .logo {
        order: 0;
    }
    .item {
        order: 1;
    }
    .button {
        order: 2;
    }
    .menu li {
        padding: 15px 10px;
    }
    .menu li.button {
        padding-right: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul class="menu">
        <li class="logo"><a href="#">Invisible App</a></li>
        <li class="item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="item"><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li class="item"><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li class="item"><a href="#">Features</a></li>
        <li class="item"><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        <li class="item"><a href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
        <li class="item button"><a href="#">Log In</a></li>
        <li class="item button secondary"><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
        <li class="toggle"><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
 
<main>
</main>
```

```
I have found this awesome tutorial for a hamburger menu using flexbox, but my jquery isn't working. I have tried to move where the jquery is in the document but have had no luck. Does anyone have any ideas why?
```

*EDIT*
I have added the CSS for the HTML below. I will also include the link to the tutorial in case I have misunderstood something or missed something. Basically, when the website is shrunk to a mobile design the hamburger icon doesn't work, I click and nothing happens. Sorry, I should have explained this earlier. There is an error in the jquery but I do not know how to fix it, I am a newbie with javascript and jquery.
    Thank you

```
    <body>

    <nav>
        <ul class="menu">
            <li class="logo"><a href="#">Invisible App</a></li>
            <li class="item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li class="item"><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li class="item"><a href="#">Services</a></li>
            <li class="item"><a href="#">Features</a></li>
            <li class="item"><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
            <li class="item"><a href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li class="item button"><a href="#">Log In</a></li>
            <li class="item button secondary"><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
            <li class="toggle"><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <main>
    </main>
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $(".toggle").on("click", function() {
            if ($(".item").hasClass("active")) {
                $(".item").removeClass("active");
                $(this).find("a").html("<i class='fas fa-bars'></i>");
            } else {
                $(".item").addClass("active");
                $(this).find("a").html("<i class='fas fa-times'></i>");
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
    </body>



nav {
    background: #222;
    padding: 5px 20px;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.logo a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.menu li {
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 15px 5px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.logo a,
.toggle a {
    font-size: 20px;
}
/* Mobile menu */
.menu {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
.toggle {
    order: 1;
}
.item.button {
    order: 2;
}
.item {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    order: 3;
    display: none;
}
.item.active {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Can you create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/1823841) here to show the issue happening. Also, add all the css class related to it main `active` class.

Comment: need add your css to question too

Comment: In this particular code fragment, there is no actual reference to JQuery. You need to open the F12 console and check for javascript errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style>
nav {
    background: #222;
    padding: 5px 20px;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.logo a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.menu li {
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 15px 5px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.logo a,
.toggle a {
    font-size: 20px;
}
/* Mobile menu */
.menu {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
.toggle {
    order: 1;
}
.item.button {
    order: 2;
}
.item {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    order: 3;
    display: none;
}
.item.active {
    display: block;
}
/* Tablet menu */
@media all and (min-width: 600px) {
    .menu {
        justify-content: center;
    }
    .logo {
        flex: 1;
    }
    .toggle {
        flex: 1;
        text-align: right;
    }
    .item.button {
        width: auto;
        order: 1;
        display: block;
    }
    .toggle {
        order: 2;
    }
    .button.secondary {
        border: 0;
    }
    .button a {
        padding: 7.5px 15px;
        background: teal;
        border: 1px #006d6d solid;
    }
    .button.secondary a {
        background: transparent;    
    }
    .button a:hover {
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    .button:not(.secondary) a:hover {
        background: #006d6d;
        border-color: #005959;
    }
    .button.secondary a:hover {
        color: #ddd;
    } 
}
/* Desktop menu */
@media all and (min-width: 900px) {
    .item {
        display: block;
        width: auto;
    }
    .toggle {
        display: none;
    }
    .logo {
        order: 0;
    }
    .item {
        order: 1;
    }
    .button {
        order: 2;
    }
    .menu li {
        padding: 15px 10px;
    }
    .menu li.button {
        padding-right: 0;
    }
}
</style>
<nav>
    <ul class="menu">
        <li class="toggle"> <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></a> fadfsadf </li>
        <li class="logo"><a href="#">Invisible App</a></li>
        <li class="item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="item"><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li class="item"><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li class="item"><a href="#">Features</a></li>
        <li class="item"><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        <li class="item"><a href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
        <li class="item button"><a href="#">Log In</a></li>
        <li class="item button secondary"><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>

    </ul>
</nav>

<main>
</main>
<script>

$(function() {
    console.log("here");
    $(".item").on("click", function() {
        console.log("clicked");
        if ($(".item").hasClass("active")) {
            $(".item").removeClass("active");
            $(this).find("a").html("<i class='fas fa-bars'></i>");
        } else {
            $(".item").addClass("active");
            $(this).find("a").html("<i class='fas fa-times'></i>");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Copy above code and paste it into editor and save it test.html and run on browser and click on any menu jquery is working now and menu also hiding. Jquery js should be added at first.Hope it helps thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should add the reference for the jQuery library before the script tags...
Add this line before the script tag

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.min.js"></script>
```